# c++ MFC accessing multiple files

Tags: mfc, directory, c++-cli

I'm working with visual studio 2012. 
In status quo, in MFC form there is a input box and it takes entire directory path of mp3 file which will be used in MFC. However, the files should be clicked and selected to be executed and this is very laborious job.

Currently, the file path is saved in `this->tb_filePath->Text` form in MFC, and after the `private: System::Void Run_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)` is clicked, a function gets the file path saved above and executes.

Since all the mp3 files are saved in specific directory, I tried to make this process automatically.  Also in directory,

```
xxxxx.mp3
aaxxx.txt
xxxx1.mp3
aaxx1.txt
```

there are mp3 formats and txt formats, I have to distinguish those files also. txt is not allowed as an input. But I'm not familiar with window-MFC form right now, so I'm not sure how can I start with this.

First, how can I automatically access to the directory and read the files that will be used in the .exe program. And how can I know that I have found all the files?

Second is it possible to select next files in folder when I press the certain button of the MFC?

Overall, I am not sure how can I search through all the .mp3 files in certain directory without selecting it one by one.

Comment: Not quite clear what you want. Maybe you need [FindFirstFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: `System::Object^` isn't C++. What language/platform are you using?

Comment: Show us the actual code....

Comment: @IInspectable i'ts managed c++, a Microsoft thing (juste added that tag)

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Visual Studio 2012 doesn't support *"managed C++"*. The [info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/managed-c%2b%2b/info) on the [tag:managed-c++] tag you added explains: *"Managed C++ is a now deprecated Microsoft language derived from C++. Do not apply this tag to C++/CLI questions."* But then, this question could be about C++/CX just as well. Only the OP can know. All we know is: It **certainly** isn't about *"managed C++"*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was solved. It was just a problem dealing with directory and file relations. sorry for the poor questioning.

Comment: Hm. Unless you will fix the question and elaborate on the answer, I would just delete both...